# Horizontal Scroll Bar in flutter

Tags: flutter, user-interface, dart

I am new to flutter, I need to add an horizontal scroll bar as in the image, how can I go about in doing so. https://i.stack.imgur.com/rfsNB.png

Answer (score 0):

you can test with a **ListView**, and using the property `scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal`.

You can get more info in this link:
https://flutter.dev/docs/cookbook/lists/horizontal-list

Answer (score 0):

you can just wrap your widget with the Scrollbar() widget and it will do your job

for further information you can read the docs here

https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/Scrollbar-class.html